# how to navigate to different components based on different query parameters of the same path

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

Let us consider a scenario where we have /instructors displaying a list of Instructors and then I want /instructors?id=someId to display details of a particular instructor with id as someId. How to specify the path in Routes array in app-routing.module.ts?

I am using

```
<a [routerLink]="['/instructors']" [queryParams]="{id:instructor.id}">
```

in my template of InstructorList component.
Also specifying path like

```
const routes:Routes=[
    {path:'instructors',component:InstructorlistComponent},
    {path:'instructors', component:InstructorComponent}
];
```

did not work.

Answer (score 2):

I think that's not possible.

I would do something like this:

```
const routes:Routes=[
    {path:'instructor/:instructor_id',component:InstructorComponent},
    {path:'instructors', component:InstructorlistComponent}
];
```

You could then also redirect to the InstructorComponentList in the InstructorComponent if the page is called without parameters

Comment: This is the correct and RESTful approach. If you really want to achieve this behavior with query parameters (which is not recommended), you have to create a wrapper component, which uses `ngIf` in order to display a component based on the query parameters.